# Record count - related list

Tags: related-list

Is there a way to show the exact count of record in related list? if record are grater than 5 we have 5+
Attached an example.

Many thanks!

[image]

Comment: classic or lightning? doable in both but depends on where you want

Comment: Hello @Rao  Classic version

Comment: do you want this in visualforce or standard page layout?

Comment: standard page layout and standard object (contacts, account team etc...). Have the exact number (ex 16 instead of 5+)

Comment: I stand corrected, I assumed this was through a VF page that you wanted to display the count, if it is standard page AFAIK there is no way to show exact count.

Answer (score 1):

For standard pages, there is no org-wide setting for this. However, an individual user can control how many records they see: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000025257&type=1. If I'm reading this correctly, once you increase the limit on a page, that limit will be increased for all related lists.